# Shader fallback logic

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, gpu

The [Unity Shader Fallback](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Fallback.html) says  Shader will auto fallback when can't run on current hardware. However, in my project, there is a shader compiler error, [Mali-400](https://github.com/hrydgard/ppsspp/issues/1816).

How does Unity evaluate if the hardware can run this shader or not?